# Does websockets work with SPDY?

Tags: javascript, websocket, spdy

I'm using socket.io, if I use a SPDY server for my app would socket.io / websockets still work?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted down. Seems like an interesting, relevant question.

Answer (score 7):

SPDY is basically a variation of HTTP/S that accelerates web page load time. WebSockets is not HTTP (even though it has an HTTP compatible initial handshake). They are unrelated (except that they both address web latency) and they are compatible. Your SPDY enabled web server may not support forwarding of WebSockets connections, but you can always run your WebSockets server standalone on a different port if that is the case.

Answer (score 5):

There is work in progress to enable WebSockets over SPDY. Chrome currently has an experimental flag for this: `--enable-websocket-over-spdy`. To track latest progress and status on this, checkout the spdy-dev discussions on google groups.

Comment: WebSocket over SPDY - is an idea of running many WebSockets in parallel over SPDY, which is not supported in most of modern browsers.

But it is optional thing, and you still can use ordinary WebSocket protocol with SPDY, because WebSocket uses it's own TCP connection which is not coupled with the current HTTP connection.